# Having troubles creating a few methods

Tags: java, object, methods, jgrasp

I'm currently in a process of making a program to store tractor rental data and I'm running into a problem in my tractor class, I'm required to override the toString method to print out all of the info of the tractors and also a method to calculate the rental profit which is just rental days*rentalrate but i'm getting these errors and i'm not sure where to go from here.

```
public int RentalProfit(int RentalRate, int RentalDays)  
    {
      RentalProfit = RentalRate * RentalDays;
      return this.RentalProfit;
    }   


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "Tractor (Rental days = " + RentalDays + ", Rental Rate = " + RentalRate + 
        "Rental profit = " RentalProfit + ", VehicleID = " + VehicleID ")";
    }
```

heres the errors:

```
Tractor.java:59: error: ';' expected
        "Rental profit = " RentalProfit + ", VehicleID = " + VehicleID ")";
                          ^
Tractor.java:59: error: not a statement
        "Rental profit = " RentalProfit + ", VehicleID = " + VehicleID ")";
                                                           ^
Tractor.java:59: error: ';' expected
        "Rental profit = " RentalProfit + ", VehicleID = " + VehicleID ")";
                                                                      ^
3 errors



public static void main(String[] args){
          Tractor tractor;
          tractor = new Tractor();
          tractor.setRentalRate(9);
          tractor.setRentalDays(45);
          tractor.setVehicleID(9145949);
          toString();
```

Heres error:

```
testTractor.java:11: error: non-static method toString() cannot be referenced from a static context
          toString();
          ^
1 error
```

Comment: Two missing `+`: `"Rental profit = " + RentalProfit + ", VehicleID = " + VehicleID + ")";`

Comment: In your main: `toString()` should be `tractor.toString()`;

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `+` sign:

```
    return  "Tractor (Rental days = " + RentalDays + ", Rental Rate = " + RentalRate + 
    "Rental profit = " + RentalProfit + ", VehicleID = " + VehicleID + ")";
                       ^                                             ^ 
                     here                                        and here
```

Comment: Even 2 if you look attentively. :-)

Comment: Another question. So I'm my main tractor class I'm trying to implment this toString() into a tractor object how should I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

In your main method you are calling `toString();` you can't do that - toString is not a static method, and must be called via an instance. What you want is `tractor.toString();`

Comment: Yeah I figured that out now its giving me this output, Tractor (Rental days = 9145949, Rental Rate = 0, Rental profit = 0, VehicleID = 9145949)
 Which i'm not sure why its doing that.

Answer (score 0):

first error you return string you must close it like this

```
 return  ("Tractor Rental days = " + RentalDays + " Rental Rate = " + RentalRate + 
        "Rental profit = "+ RentalProfit + ", VehicleID = " + VehicleID );
```

in the second problem 
i think you have main method and it's static you need make static method to call it make the method toString() static... 
i hope i help you